# How to add Read Time to AstroPaper blog

Tags: css, reactjs, markdown, blogs, astrojs

I just wanted to read-time to blog posts, I have already tried to add read-Time docs given by the Astro itself but ended in vain. Here is the blog [repo](https://github.com/satnaing/astro-paper) .

Kindly help me figure out how to implement this.

Thank you.

I needed an step-by-step process on how to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: related?: https://astro-paper.pages.dev/posts/how-to-add-estimated-reading-time/

Answer (score 1):

Hello `AstroPaper` maintainer here!

I know this question has been posted for some months now and you might already have a solution.

But for those who stumble upon this problem, I've made [a blog post](https://astro-paper.pages.dev/posts/how-to-add-estimated-reading-time/) about this specific issue. The blog post has been updated to reflect the latest version of `AstroPaper`.

If you are using `AstroPaper` prior to v4, you can check this [previous blog post](https://b5a84eef.astro-paper.pages.dev/posts/how-to-add-estimated-reading-time/). Alternatively, you can also clone the repo, checkout v3 and refer to that post.

```bash
git checkout v3.0.0
```

Hope this helps.